# Lyx: problem with ^ after last update

Tags: lyx, update

I use Lyx in Xubuntu 18.04. Yesterday I installed a system update via the "software update" application, and now I cannot write x² in math mode because when I hit the key '^' instead of introduce the '^' symbol it seems to be introducing '\^'. I mean, this is what I get in Lyx:

[image]

and there  is no way to introduce this:

[image]

using only the keyboard.

---

I have recorded a screencast showing the screen refresh problem in [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uzv5atvoafaeioe/screencast.mp4?dl=0).

Comment: Very strange. I don't think I've heard of this problem before. I use LyX daily on Ubuntu and have not seen this. What does `apt-cache policy lyx` show for you?

Comment: I shows me [this](https://image.ibb.co/f78UTe/imagen.png).

Comment: I'm not sure what went wrong. I'm using 2.3.1 (but not from the PPA, I self-compiled). On Mint, we have heard of some weird issues with fonts, but I don't remember the symptoms being like what you described. It seems more like the keymaps got confused somewhere. You could try 1. exiting LyX; 2. moving your LyX user directory to somewhere else; 3. restarting LyX. If this does fix the problem, please do not remove your old user directory. We should figure out what the root problem was.

Comment: When you say "LyX user directory" do you mean the ".lyx" directory located in home? If yes, then I did that and the problem was not fixed. Also, what about the screen refresh problem? As far as [I have read](https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg107927.html) the update included changes in the way the screen is refreshed. Maybe it is a bug?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant (it is the directory listed in Help > About). Yes, it could be that an update caused the bug, but it is strange that I do not see it on my system. I'm not sure what to suggest further.

Comment: I have reported the bug (see [this link](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11323#comment:2)) and they told me that it will be fixed in the future version. The problem is that I use Lyx everyday and I need it working again as soon as possible. Do you know how can I do to install my previous version? The update log history from yesterday is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPm2v.png). I am not an expert but it seems that I had version 2.3.0-1 and it was updated to 2.3.1-2. I don't know how to return to 2.3.0-1.

Comment: I'm not sure. We can help you compile LyX yourself (it is not that hard) if you email lyx-users@lists.lyx.org. That way, you can compile (and install) any version you want. In fact, you could compile the "development 2.3.2" version, which will have the fix included.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to a LyX bug that was introduced in version 2.3.1, and should be fixed with LyX version 2.3.2. The bug report and relevant discussion can be found [here](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11323).